# String Allocation and initialization

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone Dev - NSString Creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210319/iphone-dev-nsstring-creation)

i am using

```
 NSString   *str_Message; 
if ([txt_NoOfPersons.text length] == 0){
    bln_Validate  = FALSE;
    str_Message  = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"Number of Persons field is required."];
}
else if ([txt_NoOfPersons.text intValue] == 0)
{
    bln_Validate  = FALSE;
    str_Message  = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"Please enter your guest count."];}
}
if ([txt_DateAndTime.text length] == 0)
{
    bln_Validate  = FALSE;
    str_Message  = [[NSStrin@"Date and Time field is required."];

}
```

insted of that if i use **Nsstring *str_Message=nil;** '

```
if ([txt_NoOfPersons.text length] == 0)
{
    bln_Validate  = FALSE;
    str_Message  = @"Number of Persons field is required.";
}
else if ([txt_NoOfPersons.text intValue] == 0)
{
    bln_Validate  = FALSE;
    str_Message  = @"Please enter your guest count.";

}
```

then what will be the effect and what is difference between **Nsstring *str;  Nsstring *str=nil**

Comment: i want to know what is the difference between them only setting it to nil remove the garbage value

Answer (score 2):

When using ARC, there is no difference between `NSString *str;` and `NSString *str = nil;` , all pointers are guaranteed to be nil upon initialization.

When you aren't using ARC the pointer may point to a garbage value.

Comment: i am not  using ARC.what will happen when u assign different value for same string for different condition..

Comment: which 1 is suitable str=@""; or str=nil; if i have to pass str value to web service